# How can RMI client sees and get all dynamic remote objects registered in a registry?

Tags: java, rmi, rmiregistry

I have a requirement that the RMI client needs to get all remote objects registered in a remote RMI registry.

First question, I know there is a method of registry.list() that returns all names of the objects. However how do I get the objects of exactly the type I want (implementing the interface that I want), supposed that there are also other kinds of objects registered as well. Shall I traverse the names and use a try/catch statement, trying to instanced each remote objects?

Second question, how can a client gets noticed if a new object is registered? In my requirement, the servers will dynamicly registered new objects in to registry, and the client needs to get updated and access the new objects sooner. Shall I just use a thread to periodically list all names to find out new objects?

Please note that the remote objects are to be exported from different nodes, but not from a same node. I know if they are from the same node, possibly I can use the call-back feature called from one of the instanced remote-object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can RMI client sees and get all dynamic remote objects registered in a registry?

By calling `Naming.list()` or `Registry.list().`

> I have a requirement that the RMI client needs to get all remote objects registered in a remote RMI registry.

See above.

> How do I get the objects of exactly the type I want (implementing the interface that I want), supposed that there are also other kinds of objects registered as well? Shall I traverse the names and use a try/catch statement, trying to instanced each remote objects?

Just traverse the names returned by `list()`; `lookup()` each one; and use `instanceof` to determine whether it is of a type you need. If the Registry contains stubs you don't have all the necessary classes for at the client, you'll need to catch `ClassNotFoundException`. An easy way to do all this in fewer steps is via the JNDI [`listBindings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#listBindings(java.lang.String)) method.

> Second question, how can a client gets noticed if a new object is registered?

It can't. There is no listener system defined for the RMI Registry. The client will have to poll.

> In my requirement, the servers will dynamicly registered new objects in to registry, and the client needs to get updated and access the new objects sooner. Shall I just use a thread to periodically list all names to find out new objects?

Yes.

> Please note that the remote objects are to be exported from different nodes, but not from a same node.

You'll find that difficult to arrange, as you can only call `bind()` and friends from the same host as the Registry. You'll have to organize some intermediate remote objects to do the registering for each non-local node.

> I know if they are from the same node, possibly I can use the call-back feature called from one of the instanced remote-object.

Being from the same node isn't a precondition for that. You can do RMI callbacks in any topology where firewalls don't get in the way.

Comment: An even easier way without the `ClassCastExceptions` is via `javax.naming.Context.list()` method, which returns an enumeration of pairs `{name, class-name}, without retrieiving the objects.

Comment: When I tried to look into the usage of javax.naming, I found the following interface: javax.naming.event.NamingListener.  From the description it looks like it can be used to listen to the event of naming changes, like adding a name, etc.  Is this applicable to my requirement?

Comment: I tried javax.naming.Context.list(), but do not know the reason why the getClassName() always return java.lang.object, rather than the actual running class name...
And if I tried listBindings(), it always return com.sun.proxy.$Proxy#, where # is a number....

Comment: I ended up with the solution of try/catch to catch the ClassCastException and ignore it. It does not look a good solution, but I don't know why both Context.list() and Context.listBindings() do not return the real class name. Even if I tried the method of object.getClass().getName(), it returns the name of $Proxy. I think I will post another question in detail of this and feel free to comment on that. Thank you any way!

Comment: The RMI Registry does not support `NamingListeners`. `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy#` *is* the real class name: the class name of the dynamic proxy.